# Changing an apex map value using JavaScript w/ No remote action

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, map

My map looks something like this:

```
public Map<String, Attachment> newImageAttachmentToNameMap {get; set;}
```

I set it in Apex and then want to change some of the values through JavaScript. *On a side note - I cannot do it using Remote Actions because the map is not static.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `apex:actionFunction` which would call your controller's instance method which would then update your `Map`. There's a `name` property on the `apex:actionFunction`, which can be used to invoke it from JavaScript.